# ?cb=1 in "Hot Meta Posts" section breaking functionality of visited link colors

Tags: bug, hyperlinks

After browsing on Meta, then going back to the main site, I often see questions I've already seen shining bright blue in the Hot Meta Questions section. I suspect this is due to the `?cb=1` which is appended to the links inside the sidebar, probably for statistical reasons.

I think this makes it harder to tell at a glance if you've seen that question already or not, and if it is/isn't worth clicking (again).

The possible fix could be to remove that additional `?cb=1`, and use other means of collecting statistics if the team is that desperate to know where the users visited the particular question from.

Comment: I guess that's more [meta-tag:feature-request] unless you want a [meta-tag:status-bydesign], but whatever.

Comment: @Deduplicator I found the [tag:bug] tag's wiki more approperiate in this case, since I `believe [the problem] is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error`.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed this too, but I'd call it a feature request, not a bug.

Comment: On Chrome, if you roll over the "unvisited" links they go the visited colour as expected if you have visited them.

Comment: Definite bug (unless it is status-bydesign); the URLs are different, so the `:visited` CSS isn't getting used.

Answer (score 15):

Through for the feature request (if it ever changes to that): be clever and do the same as Google. In the generated HTML use the normalized link, then in a `mousedown` hook, use a function to append the `?cb=1` and voila!

Essentially, [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/41540/27973).

Comment: It's actually not that simple, because the two *have to match*. Sure we can append the querystring on the mousedown event, but *that's* the one that's not read/visited in your browser. The one *without* the querystring is not visited and still shows as such in the styling. There's another component here where we need to replace or push history state on the other end to mark the non-querystring version read as well. Or, you have to have a 302 on every click like Google does - which isn't something we want users to suffer.