# Question links now have annoying suffix

Tags: support, status-completed, search, hyperlinks

In the [search listing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=zombie) on both SO and MSO, questions seem to have gained an annoying query string suffix, I'm guessing to indicate which position in the list the question appears and the second part appears to be search relevance. For example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345/question1?s=1|0.9000
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345/question2?s=2|0.8000
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345/question3?s=3|0.7000
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345/question4?s=4|0.6000
```

So this means I never know if I've previously visited a question when I refresh the page and the position has moved (by seeing the link has been visited)

Is it just me? Has it been intentionally added? Can it be turned off please?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242925/why-relevance-points-are-added-to-the-querystring-of-search-results

Comment: Ah, didn't search there as I could only see the query strings on here. Guess I'll close this one...

Comment: Well... that question is about what those are... this is... different.

Comment: Hmm I suppose so. I'll leave it for now as this is a request to turn it off (I hate it!)

Comment: @DavidG to be clear: the problem is the "unread" status, correct? That's definitely an unintended side-effect we're looking at now.

Comment: @NickCraver Absolutely, I don't mind them being there, if there were another way for you to track it while keeping the links marked as visited, that would be great.

Comment: @NickCraver: another issue is that various tools that work on the links (such as the [SE Comment Link helper](http://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper)) trip over the query string too. I keep having to clean those up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Indeed, I've got my own *Monkey script for now to strip the query string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (and David OP notify) - We are pushing out a few of changes that should resolve these things for all but IE users. They're deploying now and should be visible within about 10 minutes.

Comment: @NickCraver: \o/ I don't care about IE anyway. :-P

Comment: @NickCraver: I do care about [middle click / CMD-click](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276032/question-links-now-have-annoying-suffix) however..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm yes, Ctrl-click doesn't work but middle-click still does (though I may have customised my mouse action for that anyway)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I've created a <strike>terrible hack</strike> fix to make it so that search links will correctly appear as visited. This will work for browsers that are modern... in other words not IE < 11. The fix is now live and you should be seeing the desired behaviour.

Comment: That should be "in other words," not "and."

Comment: @rightføld fair enough. Updated.

Comment: This works perfectly for me! :)

Comment: Can you use the same magic for the related and community-bulletin side-bars? (The `&rq=1` and `?cb=1`-suffixes...)

Comment: @Deduplicator [*ahem*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273161/cb-1-in-hot-meta-posts-section-breaking-functionality-of-visited-link-colors)

Comment: @DJDavid98: Forgot about that one... Still, no official reaction on it.

Comment: You broke the [middle click action](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276138/ctrlclick-and-shiftclick-do-not-open-new-tabs-windows-in-search-results) now..

Comment: Would you mind to detail the terrible hack, what technique was used?