# Ctrl+Click and Shift+Click do not open new tabs/windows in search results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When I perform a search, I often want to open several results in new tabs using Ctrl+Click. Until recently, I don't remember having any problem doing this.

Today, I cannot open search results in new tabs using modifier keys. For example, when Ctrl+Click-ing on any link in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foobar, the operation is treated as a normal click. I can still use "Open in new tab" in the context menu, but that's quite a bit slower.

I can reproduce this behavior in Firefox and Chrome for Windows.

This behavior does not appear on a few other SE sites I tested.

Comment: Works fine for me in FF for Windows.

Comment: Confirmed in both Chrome and Safari on Mac.

Comment: Related: [Question links now have annoying suffix](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276032). It is the changes the team made for that issue that are the cause here, I'm sure.

Comment: Same is happening here in FF33.

Comment: Chrome 38 on Ubuntu - confirmed.

Comment: Ctrl+Click works fine for me from search with IE 11, but Shift+Click doesn't.

Comment: Control+Click works fine under IE10, but Shift+Click doesn't.  Both work fine on other links.

Comment: safari mac repro

Comment: Hmmm... I've always used middle-click for that. Reproduced in Chrome 40.0.2211.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can repro FF 33.0.2 on windows.  Middle click works (opens in new tab), ctrl-click does not open in new tab.

Comment: Confirmed both on Firefox 31 on Ubuntu - Neither shift-click nor ctrl-click work, but middle-click does

Comment: Is this fixed now? I can't repro on Chrome 38, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yes, it appears to have been fixed within the last hour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I indeed broke this with my crummy JS, and it has now been fixed. The fix is already live so you should not have any further issues. Sorry for the inconvenience.

And for anyone curious, `this.href =` will preserve middle clicks, while `window.location.href =` will not. Now I know. :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit? What is `this`? Is it the `window` object or `document` object? Neither seems to work for me.

Comment: @Mark `this` is the anchor `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 13):

The problem seems to be here:

```
    $(".js-search-results").on("click", "div.result-link a", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = $(this).data("searchsession");
        return false;
    });
```

this finds the clicks on search results, prevents the default handler, and changes the current webpage.

Comment: Indeed, if I remove the `result-link` class of parent `<div>`, things work normally. This would certainly seem to be the problem code.

Comment: Sounds like this event handler should be a simple `this.href = $(this).data("searchsession"); return true;`

Comment: @Bergi Don't know about the assignment, but the whole callback looks odd to me.  Returning `false` in jQuery automatically calls `ev.preventDefault()`, so that's not needed.  But it sounds like that's the cause of the bug, so don't even bother with returning `true` - jQuery treats that the same as if there was no returned value...

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this with Google Chrome. However I always use
[Middle-click](http://microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/help/support/how-to/mouse/default-assignments)
for this task, which appears to be unaffected.

Comment: My laptop doesn't have a middle click button.

Comment: @Scimonster Clicking left and right at the same time is usually configured to act as a middle click

Comment: @Izkata Awesome! Who know?! (You, apparently. ;))