# Automatically open jsFiddle in a new tab?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, jsfiddle

jsFiddle is frequently used in web design questions to provide examples of working or non-working code.

Because links open by default in the same window/tab you're currently using, quite often I'll view the query, close the tab, and lose the question.

Obviously this isn't hard to remedy on a case by case basis, but is there an argument for SO detecting jsFiddle links and automatically setting the target to "_blank"? It's almost always the case that I'll want to have both the fiddle and the question open at the same time.

Comment: dup-closed duplicate on parent meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199436/jsfiddle-and-other-live-code-services-in-new-tab

Comment: They refuse to do this.  Try to remember to ctrl-click.  If you close the tab, hit ctrl-shift-T, which reopens the last tab, including history.  You can then hit the back arrow.

Comment: I just wanted to ask the same question but as I see there are already some. I find it would be very usefull if you could set it in your settings like for every search engine that I know.

Answer (score 11):

Just configure your browser to open links in new tabs / windows.

This is not something that should "configured" site-side.

A few simple alternatives would be:

- Do you have a mouse with a scroll wheel? Click that wheel on the link, it opens the link in a new tab.
- Press Ctrl and click a link.(Opens the link in a new tab in the background.)
- Press Ctrl+Shift and click a link. (Opens the link in a new tab and switches to the newly opened tab.)
- Press Shift and click a link. (Opens the link in a new window.)

Comment: But it's not something I'd always want to happen...

Comment: It's not something I'd always even want to happen on SO with anything other than jsFiddle - when navigating between questions, for example, I'm very happy to keep things in one tab.

Comment: Yes, as I said, it's easy to remedy on a case-by-case basis, I'm talking about a permanent fix.

Comment: Different users have different preferences. There is _really_ no good reason to make fiddle links behave differently from _all_ other links on the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus Of course, ctrl-click may [not work](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276138/ctrlclick-and-shiftclick-do-not-open-new-tabs-windows-in-search-results) for a while

Comment: It's a really poor answer. Why don't just let us to decide ourselves what is better for us in the settings? Just like google has it or any other search engine for example.

Comment: @t3chb0t: This _"Really poor answer"_ is currently at +9 votes. "Open page at..."- functionality like this should really not be determined by the site, simply because there is no reliable way to do so. If you disagree with an answer, it doesn't make that answer a "poor" one.

Comment: Yes with two downvotes (one is mine). There isn't? And what happened to the old `target="_blank"`? If we had an option in the settings _open links in posts in new tab_ the script could just add this attribute to a link. You could ask a question on SO how to do it ;-)

Comment: Browsers can easily be configured to ignore `target="_blank"`. I repeat: _"there is no __reliable__ way to do so"_.

Two downvotes versus 11 upvotes. Still doesn't quite seem to qualify as "Poor".

Comment: Hehe ;-) there is no reliable solution for anything. Someone can just disable JavaScript and nothing would work either. If there is someone who decides to ignore the `target` attribute he probably won't set it in the setting to use it. It doesn't have to be for every one. You are calculating hundreds of uncecessary statistics and implement one million silly badges but fail in making such a basic functionality ;-|

Comment: the trouble with this is that I constantly want to do this but it's a generally unusual interaction - so I think a good exception to Nielson's rule - if it was an unusual action I'd agree this was the best way forward. all in all, I actually think a user-configurable variable would be the nicest solution

Answer (score -2):

For those who are still interested in opening links in new tabs I've created a tiny script that does that in `Chrome` and the new `Opera` with `Tempermonkey`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StackOverflow Link Tuner
// @namespace    http://www.stackoverflow.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Opens QA links in a new tab
// @author       t3chb0t
// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var postLinks = $('div.post-text a');
postLinks.attr('target', '_blank');
```

It works both for questions and answers but not for comments (yet?).

Version for *optimizers* and *hardcore debuggers*:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StackOverflow Link Tuner
// @namespace    http://www.stackoverflow.com/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Opens QA links in a new tab
// @author       t3chb0t
// @match        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

$('div.post-text a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Why  would you assign the jquery object to a temporary variable? And you could just configure your browser to open links in a new tab in the first place.
Besides, this won't work for any link that got added to the page after page load (New answers / comments, edited posts, to name a few)

Comment: Why not? For debugging purposes of course. Everyone who has some experience does it ;-) ... and I don't want to open all links every time in a new page but just those.

Comment: @Cerbrus are you in the SO team developing the website or are just a casual user?

Comment: If I were a SO dev, it'd say that on my profile.