# Would it be possible to automatically open a code in an IDE?

Tags: feature-request, code

I know that copying and pasting is not that difficult

but still, it would be a feature to automatically open an IDE with the code in an SO question, with its file type somehow coded and so the IDE would know how to handle it.

What do you think of this?

The only similar question I have found was this:

[Automatically open jsFiddle in a new tab?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276173/automatically-open-jsfiddle-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: There is no automatic about it, what SO could offer is a download link. A user might have more than one IDE installed and would still need to choose which one should take the content in the resulting download popup - it doesn't become any less effort than copy/paste to be honest.

Comment: What IDE would it open on my iPhone? Or my ChromeBook (I don't actually have a ChromeBook)?

Answer (score 8):

God, please no. One of the reasons why SE is so nice to use and so user friendly is that it doesn't force things on you. UI elements are subtle and not brash, and ads are placed thoughtfully and not flashy or otherwise intrusive. Allowing code posted in questions **to automatically assume control of your browser and open a new tab** would have to be super-super-super strict with how its allowed, would be super open to abuse and would bring forth no tangible benefit for the vast majority of people.

Tl;DR: Absolutely not.