# The hot meta links become un-visited after switching tabs in the New Nav

Tags: bug, new-nav, community-bulletin

If you switch tabs in the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav), the links in the community bulletin on the right become un-visited. This is because the new-nav is not suffixing the query string on the end `?cb=1`.

Also related: [?cb=1 in "Hot Meta Posts" section breaking functionality of visited link colors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273161/cb-1-in-hot-meta-posts-section-breaking-functionality-of-visited-link-colors)

Before: 
[image: All links are visited]

After:
[image: Hot Meta Posts are un-visited; Featured is visited]

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted as I was just about to ask exactly the same question here - it's quite annoying! I've edited the question to give a bit more detail.